# Is there any broadcast receiver for after read SMS?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

In my application I want to delete all SMS from selected number using broadcast receivers. and it should be perform after every read message(I don't want to delete unread message).

Does anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Sorry about my English (I'm not speaking good).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't found any solution for my question. but I got the solution to delete SMS before receiving using abortBroadcast() method in receiver.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(/*is selected no*/) {
           //store SMS info in separate file
           abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

and In manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of SMS clients. You will need to contact each of their developers and ask them that question.

With respect to the Messenger application that is part of the Android open source project, it has no documented or supported APIs for this.